# Как вернуть данные из формы?

Tags: java, swing

Нужно отобразить данные в форме, пользователь введет значения в текстовые поля. После нажатия на кнопку, дочерняя форма закрывается. Мне нужно получить данные, которые ввел пользователь. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

странный вопрос,

```
String str = forma.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

может пригодится:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog
```